# secure my application against session stealing all

Tags: c#, java, javascript, security

Is there any way to prevent stealing session id using firebug ?

as if some one use firebug and write document.cookie, he will get you session id ?

any suggestion

Comment: The simplest and most effective advice is generally to require SSL.

Answer (score 3):

How do you expect "him" to steal **your** session? Firebug or not, he's not going to see the sessionid in **your** cookie, or are you suggesting that he makes a lucky guess?

Comment: if you are logged in, just try to write alert(document.cookie)

Comment: @user3204111 Yes, that's how I can see my session id. How do you expect someone else to see it, unless they're looking over my shoulder? Or do you think that the session id is the same for all users.